# Membership schedule reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders

What is the best option to send reminders based on membership status? Did ever CiviCRM support schedule reminders with membership status([Documentation's](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#using-scheduled-reminders-for-memberships) first line does say that)?

I know it is possible using CiviRules but its really hard for our client to use membership related tokens in reminder message.

Comment: never tried so can't comment

Comment: I have the same question - I have an organization with a lot of members who have multiple memberships - e.g. a membership that expired 12/31/20 and another membership that will expire 12/31/21. With one expired and one current membership, if I I use "administer/communications/schedule reminders" and set up an automatic reminder for 30 days before expiration of a membership, will the person above get a reminder about his expired membership, even though he has a current membership?